# Application Cookies does not change

Tags: weblogic

I am using weblogic server for my application. 
I have configured cookies in the weblogic.xml file with the name TEST_COOKIE as below.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<weblogic-version>10.3</weblogic-version>
<session-descriptor>
    <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
    <cookie-http-only>false</cookie-http-only>
    <cookie-name>TEST_COOKIE</cookie-name>
    <cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
    <url-rewriting-enabled>false</url-rewriting-enabled>
</session-descriptor>
```

I would like to know how the value of cookie is generated by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a single server, the value is:

```
JSESSIONID=SESSION_ID!PRIMARY_JVMID_HASH!CREATION_TIME
```

If you are using a cluster, the session failover information is included like this:

```
JSESSIONID=SESSION_ID!PRIMARY_JVMID_HASH!SECONDARY_JVM_HASH!CREATION_TIME
```

Comment: what will be the value of TEST_COOKIE

Comment: The session id is randomly generated whereas the JVM hashes will be static strings of digits so that a front end server can route to individual JVMs to support session affinity. So basically, the value is strings of characters separated by ! characters. Are you trying to parse this information?